# How to serve Angular.js application ready from server without initial refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing Angular.js application. I want it to be really fast, therefore I serve it completely generated server-side when it is initially loaded. After that every change should be handled client-side by Angular with asynchronous communication with server.

I have `ng-view` attribute on central `<div>`. But now Angular regenerates content of this `<div>` even on first load, before clicking any link. I don't want this behavior because then the server-side generation of page is useless.

How to achieve that?

Comment: This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838639/html-template-filled-in-server-side-and-updated-client-side

Answer (score 1):

Although Gloopy's suggestion will work in some cases, it will fail in others (namely `ng-repeat`). AngularJS does not currently have the ability to render on the server, but this is something that (as far as I know) no other JavaScript framework does either. I also know that server-side rendering is something that the AngularJS developers are looking into, so you may yet see it in the not-too-distant future. :)

When you say you want the application to be "really fast," you should consider where exactly you want this speed. There are a lot of places to consider speed, such as time it takes to bootstrap the app, time it takes to respond, resource intensiveness, etc (you seem to be focusing on bootstrap time). There are often different trade-offs that must be made to balance performance in an application. I'd recommend reading this response to another question on performance with AngularJS for more on the subject: [Angular.js Backbone.js or which has better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458436/angular-js-backbone-js-or-which-has-better-performance/11498872#11498872)

Are you actually running into performance issues, or is this just something you predict to be a problem? If it's the later, I'd recommend building a prototype representative of your type of application to see if it really is an issue. If it's the former and it's taking your app too long to bootstrap on the client side, there may be some optimizations that you can make (for instance, inlining some model data to avoid an additional round trip, or using Gloopy's suggestion). You can also use the profiling tools in Chrome, as well as the [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) to look for slow areas in your application.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the `ng-repeat` limitation good to know. +1 for that and for Batarang that thing is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

btford: You are absolutely right that this sounds like premature optimization - it sounds that way to me either :). Another reason is, that the application should work without JS in very simple way, so this basic layout (and angular does that for me for all other pages), so there will be always rendering on server.

I found a very hacky ugly solution - I bootstrap application after first click on any internal link. After clicking it, I unbind this initial callback, update URL with `History.pushState` and bootstrap app - it grabs the new URL and regeneration is absolutely OK. Well, I'll keep looking into not-too-distant future :).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution for doing this.  It doesn't work perfectly or for everything, but it is ok at least as far as routing and the directive I made that uses ng-repeat.

https://github.com/ithkuil/angular-on-server/wiki/Running-AngularJS-on-the-server-with-Node.js-and-jsdom